# IE10 shows <span> tooltip for shorter period

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-10

I have a `<span>` tag where I have added the 'onmouseover' and 'onmouseout' attributes using the following functions

```
function mOver(obj) {       
   document.getElementById('sw_duration_span').setAttribute("title","my title");              
   document.getElementById('sw_duration_span').style.display="block";
}

function mOut(obj) {
   document.getElementById('sw_duration_span').setAttribute("title", " ");
   document.getElementById('sw_duration_span').style.display=" ";
}
```

my span block is following:

```
<span id="sw_duration_span" class="some_css_class" onmouseover="mOver(this)" onmouseout="mOut(this)" title="my title"></span>
```

When I tested this on Mozilla and Chrome, this works fine! but in IE10, the onmouseover event disappears after a few seconds. I am not sure what is wrong here! It's quite important that I get it working in all three or none!

Any help is appreciated.

My JSFiddle demo is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/m12rfz0L/2/embedded/result/

**UPDATE**

I am now getting error messages in the console ReferenceError: mOver is not defined - which is clearly wrong! I have defined both functions

Comment: Could you provide us a fiddle ?

Comment: I am trying to understand what you're doing here, but I have absolutely no clue... Do you mean the (system provided) tooltip doesn't stay....?

Comment: Why are you setting the title on hover?  By default, an element's title only displays while the cursor is hovering over the element.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work for me in Chrome 43. The title set by the javascript is never shown in the popup, just the one in the title attribute. What are you *actually* trying to accomplish?

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/m12rfz0L/11/

Comment: @SiddharthShukla      thanks...but I was hoping not to use jQuery. But in any case, why it's not working for IE? I tried JSFiddle link with IE and other browsers. Except IE, all others are keeping it active.